# Bayesian t-test assumptions

Tags: statistics, bayesian, rjags

Good afternoon,

I know that the traditional independent t-test assumes homoscedasticity (i.e., equal variances across groups) and normality of the residuals.

They are usually checked by using levene's test for homogeneity of variances, and the shapiro-wilk test and qqplots for the normality assumption.

Which statistical assumptions do I have to check with the bayesian independent t test? How may I check them in R with coda and rjags?

Comment: If you have a statistics question, ask statisticians. We answer programming questions here.

Answer (score 0):

For whichever test you want to run, find the formula and plug in using the posterior draws of the parameters you have, such as the variance parameter and any regression coefficients that the formula requires. Iterating the formula over the posterior draws will give you a range of values for the test statistic from which you can take the mean to get an average value and the sd to get a standard deviation (uncertainty estimate).

And boom, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

There might be non-parametric Bayesian t-tests. But commonly, Bayesian t-tests are parametric, and as such they assume equality of relevant population variances. If you could obtain a t-value from a t-test (just a regular t-test for your type of t-test from any software package you're comfortable with), use levene's test (do not think this in any way is a dependable test, remember it uses p-value), then you can do a Bayesian t-test. But remember the point that the Bayesian t-test, requires a conventional modeling of observations (Likelihood), and an appropriate prior for the parameter of interest.

It is highly recommended that t-tests be re-parameterized in terms of effect sizes (especially standardized mean difference effect sizes). That is, you focus on the Bayesian estimation of the effect size arising from the t-test not other parameter in the t-test. If you opt to estimate Effect Size from a t-test, then a very easy to use free, online Bayesian t-test software is [**THIS ONE HERE**](https://rezanorouzian.shinyapps.io/bayes-t/) (probably one of the most user-friendly package available, note that this software uses a `cauchy` prior for the effect size arising from any type of t-test).

Finally, since you want to do a Bayesian t-test, I would suggest focusing your attention on picking an appropriate/defensible/meaningful prior rather then levenes' test. No test could really show that the sample data may have come from two populations (in your case) that have had equal variances or not unless data is plentiful. Note that the issue that sample data may have come from populations with equal variances itself is an inferential (Bayesian or non-Bayesian) question.